# Copy first 1000 documents into another collection

Tags: mongodb

I wanted to copy few documents from one collection to another collection without using mongoexport & mongoimport i.e. like the below method in SQL.

```
select * into table1 from (select top 1000 * from sourcetable)a
```

The version of mongodb is 3.2.3. The reason for not preferring mongoexport & mongoimport because it doesn't contain rich BSON and I doubt this is creating problem at report level.

Comment: Well, how is "top 1000 defined"?

Comment: As 'first 1000 entries' or `LIMIT 1000` as equivalent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) stage of the aggregation pipeline.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$limit: 1000},
    {$out: "<output collection name>"}
])
```